# Bundle : Install gem from private github repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, github, rubygems, bundler, private

I have got trouble to bundle gems from git private repositories :

```
gem 'test', :git => 'git://github.com/my_account/test.git'

myapp_folder$ bundle --verbose
Fetching git://github.com/my_account/test.git
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/my_account/test.git' "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/cache/bundler/git/test-7b1f0bd821d503c9d6d421d89c56850dad44c15a" --bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /Users/.../myapp_forlder has failed.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/source.rb:583:in `git'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/source.rb:652:in `cache'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/source.rb:550:in `specs'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/definition.rb:356:in `converge_locked_specs'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/definition.rb:345:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/definition.rb:345:in `converge_locked_specs'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/definition.rb:143:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/definition.rb:85:in `resolve_remotely!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:43:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/bin/bundle:13
/usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/bundle:19
```

It work perfectly with push/pull/whatever the private clone it-self.

It work perfectly with bundling my public github repository.

I'm on Mac OS with bundle v 1.0.18

I also try to make some git clone my_private_repo, and it's asking me my account password. Is it normal or it should look at my ssh config and look I already have rights to access.

May be it is the point, but I don't know, how to dig further in this issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the "SSH" or "HTTP" URLs to your private repo. For example:

```
# HTTP (I've found this to be more reliable)
gem 'test', :git => 'https://my_account@github.com/my_account/test.git'
# SSH
gem 'test', :git => 'git@github.com:my_account/test.git'
```

Don't guess them, though. You can get them by going to your github repo page... there are three options at the top.

It's normal to enter a password if it asks.

Comment: The SSH URL worked for me, at least locally. Should be fun to get this working on CI and everything else. Thanks :)

Comment: On Mac, the error can be weird, for me running the git clone command in terminal window showed the actual error.

git clone https://github.com/alexdunae/validates_email_format_of.git


Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.

Comment: Is there a way to ask git to find key in pageant instead of manual input? I have pageant with the correct key. But it looks like bundle install just ignore them

Answer (score -2):

add this in your ~/.gitconfig

```
[url "https://"]
   insteadOf =git://
```